# does it charge extra? or is there an extra change?

Tags: questions

If I want to ask if something (like wifi) charges extra, which sounds more natural: does it charge extra? or is there an extra charge?

Answer (score 1):

The *provider* of the WiFi might "charge extra" (for example the owner of a hotel), but the WiFi *itself* does not, since it is not an active participant in the business transaction. It would be more natural to say that "there is an extra charge" for the WiFi as you suggest.

Comment: The WiFi might *cost* extra though, if the OP wanted to use the other word order.